# Loading Data into Spark Dataframe without delimiters in source

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with no delimiters:

```
111222333444
555666777888
```

Desired output:

```
|_c1_|_c2_|_c3_|_c4_|
|111 |222 |333 |444 |
|555 |666 |777 |888 |
```

i have tried this to attain the output

```
val myDF = spark.sparkContext.textFile("myFile").toDF()
val myNewDF = myDF.withColumn("c1", substring(col("value"), 0, 3))
                  .withColumn("c2", substring(col("value"), 3, 6))
                  .withColumn("c3", substring(col("value"), 6, 9)
                  .withColumn("c4", substring(col("value"), 9, 12))
             .drop("value") 
             .show()
```

but i need to manipulate c4 (multiply 100) but the datatype is string not double.

Update: I encountered a scenarios 
when i execute this,

```
val myNewDF = myDF.withColumn("c1", expr("substring(value, 0, 3)"))
.withColumn("c2",  expr("substring(value, 3, 6"))
.withColumn("c3", expr("substring(value, 6, 9)"))
.withColumn("c4", (expr("substring(value, 9, 12)").cast("double") * 100))
.drop("value")
```

`myNewDF.show(5,false)` // it only shows "value" column (which i dropped) and "c1" column

`myNewDF.printSchema`  // only showing 2 rows. why is it not showing all the newly created 4 columns?

Comment: What have you tried yourself thus far?

Comment: val myDF = spark.sparkContext.textFile("<myFile>").toDF()
val myNewDF = myDF.withColumn("c1", substring(col("value"), 0, 3)).withColumn("c2", substring(col("value"), 3, 6)).show()

Comment: different question now I see

Comment: See amended answer based on your new and last question.

Comment: Why are copying everyone's answer as your own. Not really nice behaviour here on SO and against the principles. I re-ran my answer and it shows everything fine - as I knew it would.

Comment: Screenshot  attached you must be making some sort of elementary error. Review your code.

Comment: Yes i have discovered the error, i have a carriage return before each `.withColumn` which is causing the issue

Comment: Glad it worked out. Success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving a little to puzzle for yourself, like 1) reading the file and naming your dataset / dataframe columns explicitly, this simulated approach with RDD should help you on your way:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("111222333444"), 
                             ("555666777888")
                            )
                        )

val df = rdd.map(x => (x.slice(0,3), x.slice(3,6), x.slice(6,9), x.slice(9,12))).toDF()  
df.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|_1 |_2 |_3 |_4 |
+---+---+---+---+
|111|222|333|444|
|555|666|777|888|
+---+---+---+---+
```

OR

using DF's:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("111222333444"), 
                        ("555666777888"))
                    ).toDF()

val df2 = df.withColumn("c1", expr("substring(value, 1, 3)")).withColumn("c2", expr("substring(value, 4, 3)")).withColumn("c3", expr("substring(value, 7, 3)")).withColumn("c4", expr("substring(value, 10, 3)"))
df2.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+------------+---+---+---+---+
|value       |c1 |c2 |c3 |c4 |
+------------+---+---+---+---+
|111222333444|111|222|333|444|
|555666777888|555|666|777|888|
+------------+---+---+---+---+
```

you can drop the value, leave that up to you.

Like the answer above but gets complicated if not all 3 size chunks.

Your updated question for double times 100:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("c1", expr("substring(value, 1, 3)")).withColumn("c2", expr("substring(value, 4, 3)")).withColumn("c3", expr("substring(value, 7, 3)"))
        .withColumn("c4", (expr("substring(value, 10, 3)").cast("double") * 100))
```

[image]

Comment: thank @thebluephantom, however when i execute "df2.printSchema" it only shows 2 rows. (the initial column and c1 only). pls advise. i need the created columns to perform some SQL queries

Comment: odd will look later

Comment: Odd as I see no such issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create test dataframe:

```
scala> var df = Seq(("111222333444"),("555666777888")).toDF("s")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [s: string]
```

Split column `s` into an array of 3-character chunks:

```
scala> var res = df.withColumn("temp",split(col("s"),"(?<=\\G...)"))
res: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [s: string, temp: array<string>]
```

Map array elements to new columns:

```
scala> res = res.select((1 until 5).map(i => col("temp").getItem(i-1).as("c"+i)):_*)
res: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [c1: string, c2: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> res.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+
|c1 |c2 |c3 |c4 |
+---+---+---+---+
|111|222|333|444|
|555|666|777|888|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: vals not vars is the scala paradigm

Comment: `var`s if you're running out of meaningful names